# How can I map local mail server to my domain

Tags: vpn, domain, email-server

I've setup local mail server on Linux Platform,now I'm able to access within LAN, I've purchased domain from GoDaddy, how can I map local mail server in my domain ?

I know that we need to give mail server IP in MX records of the domain but the issue is with my network architecture,once have a look

> Static IP Address from ISP---> Net Gear Router--->eth0 of Linux server;from eth1 of Linux server to LAN.

Now we are able to access mail server by using local IP address as

> 192.168.x.x/webmail or by configuring SMTP details in Thunderbird.

I want to access webmail outside of local network,how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*I Rewrote my post after getting your answers, which were: MTA=postfix, linux distro=ubuntu*, currently email from outside does not arrive)

To get you started, I leave out all the fancy anti-virus/ anti-spam setup.

If I understand your questions, what you want is:

- receive mail directed to addresses like **user@your-domain**
- access mail through a **webmailer** from anywhere

To receive email from outside you need to

- configure **postfix** to **accept** mail for user **@your-domain** and let it listen on the right interfaces
- configure your router to **forward port 25** to your linux server
- configure the **MX-record** at your DNS-provider (GoDaddy in your case) to point to your static IP

Postfix's default configuration should be ok.
Just change the host and domain names it accepts and the interfaces where postfix listens:

***Replace mail.yourdomain.com** by your fully qualified domain name and **yourdomain.com** by your domain.*

```
sudo postconf -e "mydestination = mail.yourdomain.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost, yourdomain.com"
sudo postconf -e "inet_interfaces = all"
sudo  /etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

To access mail from outside via webmailer you need to

- configure your web server to offer HTTPS
- configure your router to forward port 443 to your linux server

To enable SSL for Apache2 on ubuntu (see https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/httpd.html#https-configuration):

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This uses self signed test certificates probably issued to localhost or localhost.localdomain. This is good enough to test your setup.

You can create your own self signed certs with e.g. www.**your-domain** or buy one (which is a waste if you just need encryption IMHO).
See [Ubuntu-Certificates-Doku](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks Heiner for spending your valuable to time,below are answers to your questions 1) Currently I'm unable to send mail from outside 2) I'm accessing webmail by using "http" 3) I'm using Debian(Ubuntu server) linux distribution and MTA is postfix and MDA is Dovecot.

Comment: Uh oh! Then there is more than one task: 1. configure an externally accessible email server using postfix (avoid open relay, listen on eth0 + eth1). 2. setup GoDaddy account (MX = your static IP) 3. forward port 25 from your router to your linux server, 4. setup SSL for your web server

Comment: I'll follow what you have explained above but for now,I just want to access webmail service from outside of local network,for that I've configured router forward port 80 to my server but I'm unable to access webmail service outside of local network.

Comment: Maybe your apache does not listen on eth1. 'netstat -t -l|grep :http' shows for which addresses HTTP is open. Do you get an error msg. BTW?

Comment: Currently I'm able to access apache server from eth0 and eth1 locally but failed to access outside even though configured port forward.After giving above cmd,it shows `tcp        0      0 *:https                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN`

Comment: Thanks now I'm able to access webmail outside using port forward option,issue is Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the mail server a publicly routable address (let it use your ISP-assigned static IP), most likely through [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) or port forwarding on your router.

How to do that specifically should be documented in the user/administrator guide for your Netgear router, though as a quick warning, SOHO equipment may not be able to handle the number of traffic or connections you'll require for a mail server if you have a respectable volume of mail, so you might run int issues that require a business or enterprise-grade router for this purpose.